# C# Float to Real in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am attempting to use Entity Framework and have a contact database that has Longitude and Latitude data from Google Maps.

The guide says that this should be stored as float.

I have created my POCO entity which includes `Longitude` as a `float` and `Latitude` as a `float`.

I have just noticed that in the database, these both come up as `real`.

There is still a lot of work to be done before I can get any data back from Google, I am very far away from testing and I was just wondering if anyone can tell me if this is going to be a problem later on?

Comment: @Pranay Rana - I haven't on answers I haven't accepted!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, that should be fine. Note that you may not get the *exact* same value back as you received from Google Maps, as that would have been expressed in decimal-formatted text. However, this is effectively a physical quantity, and thus more appropriate as a float/double/real/(whatever binary floating point type you like) than as a decimal. (Decimals are more appropriate for man-made quantities - particularly currency.)

If you look at the [documentation for `float` and `real`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) you'll see that `real` is effectively `float(24)` - a 32-bit floating binary point type, just like `float` in C#.

EDIT: As noted in comments, if you want more than the significant 7-8 digits of accuracy provided by `float`, then you probably want `double` instead in C#, which would mean `float(53)` in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but, I just manually input the data in to the database and as you said, it didn't store the exact value... a random location of 41.710855, -93.959198 was stored as 41.71085, -93.9592 ... I just tried doing a search and these locations appear to be about 3/4 of a mile out... This is a little bit to far :( ... I am guessing that this may be a difference between different language's definition of float? (I was trying to work from this example - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html ) ... Is there a workaround?

Comment: @wil: Well, if you want more than 7-8 significant digits, use `double` in the C# and `float(53)` in the database.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise that this would lead to a different question, but, thank you.

Comment: Why EF doesn't allow to set precision on float but allows for decimal? If a property is of float then I can't set its precision.

Comment: @stt106: Well if you follow the documentation, it looks like there are really only two values for the precision of `float/real` - which correspond to using `float` or `double` in C#.

Answer (score 2):

This link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258876(v=sql.80).aspx

explains that, in SQL Server, `real` is a synonym for `float(24)`, using 4 bytes of data.  In .NET a Single precision floating point number also uses 4 bytes, so these are pretty much equivalent:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7(v=vs.71).aspx